# what does the file Snapshot.scala in databricks?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I am running some streaming query jobs on a databricks cluster, and when i look at the cluster/job logs, I see a lot of

> first at Snapshot.scala:1

and

> withNewExecutionId at TransactionalWriteEdge.scala:130

A quick search yielded this scala script https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/Snapshot.scala
Any one can explain what this do in laymans term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Internally this class manages the replay of actions stored in checkpoint or [delta file](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/master/PROTOCOL.md#file-types)

Generally, this "snapshotting" relies on [delta encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) and indirectly allows [snaphot isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_isolation) as well.

Practically delta-encoding remembers every side-effectful operation like INSERT DELETE UPDATE that you did since the last checkpoint. In case of delta lake it would be `SingleAction` ([source](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/8b011227328eba60d2be83e8a016ca50b35d84f6/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/actions/actions.scala#L58)): AddFile (insert) RemoveFile (delete). Conceptually this approach is close to event-sourcing - without it you'd have to literally store/broadcast whole state (database or directory) on every update. It also employed by many classic ACID databases with replication.

Overall it gives you:

- ability to continuously replicate file-system/directory/database state (see [SnapshotManagement.update](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/8b011227328eba60d2be83e8a016ca50b35d84f6/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/SnapshotManagement.scala)). Basically that's why you see a lot of `first at Snapshot.scala:1` - it's called in order to catch up with the log every time you start transaction, see [DeltaLog.startTransaction](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/8b011227328eba60d2be83e8a016ca50b35d84f6/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/DeltaLog.scala). I couldn't find `TransactionalWriteEdge` sources, but I guess it's called around the same time.
- ability to restore state by replaying every action since the last snapshot.
- ability to isolate (and store) transactions by keeping their snapshots apart until commit (every `SingleAction` has txn in order to isolate). Delta-lake uses [optimistic locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) for that: transaction commits will fail if their logs are not mergeable, while readers don't see uncommitted actions.

P.S. You can see that the log is accessed in line `val deltaData = load(files)` and actions are stacked on top of `previousSnapshot` (`val checkpointData = previousSnapshot.getOrElse(emptyActions); val allActions = checkpointData.union(deltaData)`)